# How do I see the (actual) foreign key value in an Access table?

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys

I have an MS Access (2003) table containing names and addresses. The addresses are repeated for cohabiting people. I intend normalising this and putting it into My SQL.

To save time I used the Access 'analyser' to split the table into two tables 'People' and 'Addresses' linked by a foreign key 'addressID' (numeric) in the People table.

However, when I view the newly created 'People' table, instead of showing me that actual, numeric, foreign key it shows a column 'Lookup to Addresses' containing a textual address.

How do I make Access show me what is **really** in the table instead of trying to be helpful and showing me what it is linked to?

(An almost identical question was asked by Eyal in Dec 20011 but did not appeared to get any answers)

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer. I had to...

1. go into the design of the table
2. select the foreign key field
3. go to the lookup tab
4. change the display control value from to combo box to
   text box
5. go to the general tab
6. delete the caption text

All that bother!

This is what I don't like about MS products. They always seen to think they know better than the user does about what the user wants!

At last my table isn't lying to me about its actual contents any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the table using SQL (e.g. SELECT * FROM [mytable])

*fixed typo

Comment: 'Select * from members' still shows a column 'Lookup to Addresses' containing a string, wherease the design for table 'members' shows the column as being called 'Address_ID' and being numeric (as it should be)

Comment: BTW, the string that the table 'members' shows instead of its actual numeric value appears to be a concatenation of the fields that were originally duplicated but have now been moved into the table 'Addresses'

Comment: @user3209752 if in your query to wrote `Select cint(lookedUpColum) from [mytable]` then it would have shown you the underlying numeric value.